# How can I access the USB drivers, USBMap, and Listen a USB port on osX?

Tags: ios, macos, usb

I'm wondering how I could access the USB (via C, objective C), and listen 
what's going on, on my USB port.

I already used the tool USB Prober located at /Developer/Applications/Utilities/
but I'd like to go a bit more deeper in the practice.

I don't find anything really interesting on the USB programming on mac, and how to modify the drivers/kernel to listen the communications between a USB device and the USB core.

Does someone have any interesting informations ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Although I would recommend that you get yourself a decent hardware analyzer, you could try installing the [debug version of IOUSBFamily](http://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/download/usbdebug.html), which combined with the USB Prober and [`usbtracer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1370/_index.html) (included in USB Prober, do note that it only outputs a limited amount of data, 8 bytes on 32 bit systems, 16 on 64 bit systems) should probably give you more information than you really want.

You may also be able to modify and rebuild [IOUSBFamily](http://opensource.apple.com/source/IOUSBFamily/IOUSBFamily-424.4.1/) (note, link points to latest version, but you should probably use the one matching your kernel) to dump larger quantities of data than what you currently get from usbtracer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i'm wondering which one to modify first IOUSBCommand, IOUSBCompositeDriver, etc. Because I don't know how to duplicate the data received.

Comment: Most data will pass through `IOUSBPipe`, Device configuration and device control requests through `IOUSBDevice`, interface configuration etc. through `IOUSBInterface`